# Case Management Option in Process Designer not available in JBPM

Tags: jboss, jbpm, bpmn

I have downloaded jBPM 7.37.0.Final server (single zip) distribution from https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html. Installed in Ubuntu machine.
I have made one change in standalone.xml file in  section just to point postgres database intead of H2.
I am using business-central for JBPM deployments.
http://localhost:8080/business-central/kie-wb.jsp

I simply added case project then i added a case definition.
But Process designer not showing case management option. See below image.[Without Case management Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4vBn.png)
I have already set below parameters for case, 
i)runtime strategy to Per Case
ii)configure marshallers for case file and documents
ii)created WorkDefinition.wid files in the project and its packages to ensure case related nodes (e.g. Milestone) are available in palette.

But still it is not showing case management option.Please help here.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.
In the case definition properties set Ad-hoc process property to true, save case, close and reopen.